# How can I determine why sublime-text 2 will no longer start for me?

Tags: 12.04, sublime-text

My sublime-text 2 editor no longer starts when I click it's icon in my dock.
The icon does the normal slow pulsing for a while (unity) but nothing seems to load.

How can I determine why sublime has started failing?

**UPDATE**
Output of $ cat /usr/share/applications/sublime-text-2.desktop

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Name=Sublime Text 2
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Sophisticated text editor for code, html and prose
Exec=/usr/bin/sublime-text-2 %F
Terminal=false
Type=Application
MimeType=text/plain;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-java;text/x-dsrc;text/x-pascal;text/x-perl;text/x-python;application/x-php;application/x-httpd-php3;application/x-httpd-php4;application/x-httpd-php5;application/xml;text/html;text/css;text/x-sql;text/x-diff;x-directory/normal;inode/directory;
Icon=sublime-text-2
Categories=TextEditor;Development;Utility;
Name[en_US]=Sublime Text 2
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow;

[NewWindow Shortcut Group]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=/usr/bin/sublime-text-2 --new-window
```

Comment: Do you see an entry for Sublime in `/usr/share/applications`?

Comment: How did you install it? Check whether it actually resides on the disk

Comment: @Sly I have /usr/share/applications/sublime-text-2.desktop

Comment: Update your question with the output from `cat /usr/share/applications/sublime-text-2.desktop`.

Comment: @Anwar I have a folder full of sublime @ /usr/bin/sublime-text-2

Comment: Do you have a file in `~/.local/share/applications` with name sublime?

Comment: @dibs You said that you have a folder at `/usr/bin/sublime-text-2`? This `sublime.desktop` is using `/usr/bin/sublime-text-2` as the executable.

Comment: @Anwar ~/.local/share/applications has no sublime of any sort..

Comment: @Sly your right, it wasn't a folder, it's the following file/links: subl -> sublime-text-2*,  sublime-text -> sublime-text-2*,  sublime-text-2*

Comment: What's with the `#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open`? I've never known `.desktop` files to have that in them.

Comment: @Sly I'm not sure. Is it a Debian desktop launcher default line? It's commented out anyway isn't it. I'm not sure what language this is.

Comment: @dibs I've never ran into that line in one of those files. I'm not sure if it would have any effect on it or not.

Comment: @Sly The answer here at [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020106/hashbang-for-gnome-desktop-files) mentions it.

Comment: @dibs Yeah. Just read up on the `.desktop` extension layout [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html). Doesn't seem like that would have any effect. I had this issue once before, but trying to remember how I solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a fix of the sublime-won't-start problem: **[link](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/revert.html)**.

Basically what it does is - it reverts the Sublime to its initial state by removing your data (and configuration) folder, which is in one of the following paths, depending on your operating system:

- OS X: ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2
- Windows: %APPDATA%\Sublime Text 2
- Linux: ~/.config/sublime-text-2

So you just exit Sublime editor, delete the data folder  (or back it up somewhere, for future needs) and then restart Sublime.

That will make Sublime work again - so then you can try redoing your steps and see what actually went wrong. At least it worked that way for me.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Tnx Oyibo for bringing that to my attention. I modified my answer so it's a bit more informative.

Comment: You're welcome, just wanted to make sure your help stays relevant if ever the link changes as your answer is exactly whats needed by the original poster ;)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with Sublime Text 3, but wasn't too keen on just ditching my config - I've installed a lot of plugins via package manager, who wants to do all that again?

I found that removing the files in .config/sublime-text-3/Local did the trick for me.  I suggest exiting ST and running this command:

```
rm ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Local/*
```

Restart ST and you'll hopefully be good to go!

Comment: Had the same, but my problem seemed to be in the Cache-directory in stead of the Local (which apparantly contains my unsaved files, and I wouldn't like to loose those).